# Is this block matrix positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices

Let $0<a<b$, and let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be two positive definite symmetric matrices.

> My question is: is the matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$ be defined by
>   \begin{align*}
> M = \begin{bmatrix}
> bA & aB\\
> aA & bB
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{align*}
>   positive definite or not? (In the sense $x^\intercal (M + M^\intercal) x >0$ for any nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$.)

I tried the following.

We know that the symmetric matrix $P$ defined by 
\begin{align*}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
bA & a(AB)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
a(BA)^{\frac{1}{2}} & bB
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
is positive definite, because it writes as
\begin{align*}
P = L^\intercal D L, \qquad \text{for }D = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
(a+b)A & 0 \\ 
0 & (b-a)A
\end{bmatrix}, \quad L = \begin{bmatrix}
I_n & A^{-\frac{1}{2}} B^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
I_n & - A^{-\frac{1}{2}} B^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and $D$ is positive definite (hence, $x^\intercal P x = (Lx)^\intercal P (Lx)>0$ for any nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$).

Moreover, one can see the following relationship between $M$ and $P$:
\begin{align*}
M = C^{-1} P C, \qquad \text{for } C = \mathrm{diag}(A^\frac{1}{2}, B^{\frac{1}{2}})
\end{align*}
Hence, we know that $M$ and $P$ have the same eigenvalues. However, $M$ is not symmetric, so I don't know if this information is of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always positive definite. Let $C=A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$. Since
$$
\pmatrix{A^{-1/2}\\ &A^{-1/2}}(M+M^T)\pmatrix{A^{-1/2}\\ &A^{-1/2}}=\pmatrix{2bI&a(I+C)\\ a(I+C)&2bC}
$$
and $C$ can be unitary diagonalised, $M+M^T$ is positive definite if and only if $\pmatrix{2b&a(1+c)\\ a(1+c)&2bc}$ is positive definite for every eigenvalue $c$ of $C$. By Sylvester's criterion, the latter condition is equivalent to $4b^2c-a^2(1+c)^2>0$, which clearly isn't always satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just have one question: why is $\pmatrix{2b&a(1+C)\\ a(1+C)&2bC}$ positive definite if and only if $\pmatrix{2b&a(1+c)\\ a(1+c)&2bc}$ is positive definite?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the case that $M+M^T$ is positive definite iff 
$$
\pmatrix{2b&a(1+\lambda)\\ a(1+\lambda)&2bc}
$$
for **all** eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $C$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh yes, you're right.

Comment: @user344045 $C$ is Hermitian and can be unitarily diagonalised. Therefore the block matrix is unitarily similar to a direct sum of $2\times2$ submatrices of the said form.

Comment: Thank you. So, from what I understood, we denote $C = U^\intercal D U$ for $U$ unitary and $D = \mathrm{diag}(c_1, \ldots, c_{2n})$ where $c_i$ are the eigenvalues of $C$, and $\pmatrix{2b&a(1+C)\\ a(1+C)&2bC} = \pmatrix{U^\intercal&0\\ 0&U^\intercal} \pmatrix{2bI&a(1+D)\\ a(1+D)&2bD} \pmatrix{U&0\\ 0&U}$. Hence, the eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{2b&a(1+C)\\ a(1+C)&2bC} $ are the union of the eigenvalues of the matrices $\pmatrix{2b&a(1+c_i)\\ a(1+c_i)&2bc_i} $.

Comment: @user344045 Yes. That is correct.